# What is the difference between state and props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was watching a Pluralsight course on React and the instructor stated that props should not be changed. I'm now reading [an article (uberVU/react-guide)](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md) on props vs. state and it says

> Both props and state changes trigger a render update.

Later in the article it says:

> Props (short for properties) are a Component's configuration, its options if you may. They are received from above and immutable.

- So props can change but they should be immutable?
- When should you use props and when should you use state?
- If you have data that a React component needs, should it be passed through props or setup in the React component via `getInitialState`?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/work-with-and-manipulate-state-in-react/   and https://appendto.com/2016/05/what-is-difference-between-props-and-state/

Comment: props are passed via component properties, they're not reactive.  State are variables that react will react , updating the UI when values changes.

Comment: I think what is meant by "props should not be changed" is that they should not be changed by children components. The parent who passes down props to children can (and likely will) change them.

Answer (score 844, accepted):

Props and state are related. The state of one component will often become the props of a child component. Props are passed to the child within the render method of the parent as the second argument to `React.createElement()` or, if you're using JSX, the more familiar tag attributes.

```
<MyChild name={this.state.childsName} />
```

The parent's state value of `childsName` becomes the child's `this.props.name`. From the child's perspective, the name prop is immutable. If it needs to be changed, the parent should just change its internal state:

```
this.setState({ childsName: 'New name' });
```

and React will propagate it to the child for you. A natural follow-on question is: what if the child needs to change its name prop? This is usually done through child events and parent callbacks. The child might expose an event called, for example, `onNameChanged`. The parent would then subscribe to the event by passing a callback handler.

```
<MyChild name={this.state.childsName} onNameChanged={this.handleName} />
```

The child would pass its requested new name as an argument to the event callback by calling, e.g., `this.props.onNameChanged('New name')`, and the parent would use the name in the event handler to update its state.

```
handleName: function(newName) {
   this.setState({ childsName: newName });
}
```

Comment: thanks! So a couple more questions: 1. why are people saying props shouldn't change? 2. where do you put your data bootstrapping? In the initialization of the component like getInitialState, or do you put it outside of the component and render the component when data is available?

Comment: 1. This is the 'functional' aspect of React. All data (almost) flows downwards. Since the prop is owned by the parent, only the parent should change it. Ideally, children should be stateless. That's not possible in practice (see forms documentation on the React site). 2. You can either feed it in at the top, which is a recommended practice, or you can store it in separate objects. One popular approach is Flux, which uses singleton objects called Stores. This is part of a larger architectural pattern. It is also open sourced from Facebook and designed to work with React.

Comment: so stores are just like big global variables?

Comment: Yes, Flux stores are client side caches. There are also other patterns like the recently released Relay, from Facebook, and Redux.

Comment: This is a little confusing to me as saying that the state of one component becomes the props of another sounds like you can only ever have ONE active parent component with a state as the rest of them will only get the props which are read only and immutable.

Do you mind if you elaborate on this a little further? Thank you

Comment: You are right in your description. Although it's possible to introduce active components further down, it becomes harder to manage and much harder to test. Dan Abramov, the creator of Redux, wrote [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), which provides a good summary of the issues involved.

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for ! State is for components changing data and passing it down to child components requires props since changing state is local to component.

Comment: To boil this down a bit: state is component data that is managed from within, props are component data that are managed from above and passed in.

Comment: Can any one explain the answer with functional component ?

Comment: The explanation doesn't really change with functional components. When you have component A (parent), you create a state "name" using the useState() hook, you then pass that state down to the child component A1 (child) as a (read-only) prop. The content of the state "name" can only be changed by component A (parent)  and not by A1 (child). Which means to change the state of "name", another prop must be passed to component A1, which will be a callback to a state update function in component A.

Answer (score 274):

For parent-child communication, simply pass props.

Use **state** to store the data your current page needs in your controller-view.

Use **props** to pass data & event handlers down to your child components.

These lists should help guide you when working with data in your components.

**Props**

- are immutable

  - which lets React do fast reference checks
- are used to pass data down from your view-controller

  - your top level component
- have better performance

  - use this to pass data to child components

**State**

- should be managed in your view-controller

  - your top level component
- is mutable
- has worse performance
- should not be accessed from child components

  - pass it down with props instead

> For communication between two components that don't have a
>   parent-child relationship, you can set up your own global event
>   system. Subscribe to events in componentDidMount(), unsubscribe in
>   componentWillUnmount(), and call setState() when you receive an event.
>   Flux pattern is one of the possible ways to arrange this.
>    -  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html
>
> **What Components Should Have State?**
>
> Most of your components should simply take some data from props and
>   render it. However, sometimes you need to respond to user input, a
>   server request or the passage of time. For this you use state.
>
> Try to keep as many of your components as possible **stateless**. By doing
>   this you'll isolate the state to its most logical place and minimize
>   redundancy, making it easier to reason about your application.
>
> A common pattern is to create several **stateless** components that just
>   render data, and have a stateful component above them in the hierarchy
>   that passes its state to its children via props. The stateful
>   component encapsulates all of the interaction logic, while the
>   stateless components take care of rendering data in a declarative way.
>      - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-components-should-have-state
>
> **What Should Go in State?**
>
> State should contain data that a component's event handlers may change
>   to trigger a UI update. In real apps this data tends to be very small
>   and JSON-serializable. When building a stateful component, think about
>   the minimal possible representation of its state, and only store those
>   properties in this.state. Inside of render() simply compute any other
>   information you need based on this state. You'll find that thinking
>   about and writing applications in this way tends to lead to the most
>   correct application, since adding redundant or computed values to
>   state means that you need to explicitly keep them in sync rather than
>   rely on React computing them for you. 
>     -  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-should-go-in-state

Comment: disagree, going all props is actually less performant to pass data down.  Just set the store for the child components, then you don't have to deal with a mess of props and when props change you have to update your components.  Just update your store and let the component get its data from its store.

Comment: Can you tell me why props are more performance than states. thanks.

Comment: @hqt I think because it's immutable, them the inside comparation to change values is faster

Answer (score 162):

> **You can understand it best by relating it to Plain
>   JS functions.**

Simply put,

**State** is the local state of the component which cannot be accessed and modified outside of the component. It's equivalent to local variables in a function.

*Plain JS Function*

```
const DummyFunction = () => {
  let name = 'Manoj';
  console.log(`Hey ${name}`)
}
```

*React Component*

```
class DummyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Manoj'
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>;
  }
```

**Props**, on the other hand, make components reusable by giving components the ability to receive data from their parent component in the form of props. They are equivalent to function parameters.

*Plain JS Function*

```
const DummyFunction = (name) => {
  console.log(`Hey ${name}`)
}

// when using the function
DummyFunction('Manoj');
DummyFunction('Ajay');
```

*React Component*

```
class DummyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }

}

// when using the component
<DummyComponent name="Manoj" />
<DummyComponent name="Ajay" />
```

Credits: [Manoj Singh Negi](https://medium.com/@manojsinghnegi)

Article Link: [React State vs Props explained](https://medium.com/@manojsinghnegi/react-state-vs-props-explained-51beebd73b21)

Comment: This is actually a very helpful answer. After reading this, I can then understand the more complete answers. Thanks.

Comment: React component = plain JS function is a brilliant way to clearly explain this. And with React moving more and more toward functional components, this is becoming even more literally the case.

Comment: I think the analogy to local variables for state is a bit simplistic. State often changes due to side-effects whose scope is not local to the function/component. Often state is mutated by HTTP calls, UX interactions etc. Props's values can also change because of side-effects, but that is not the component's concern; it's an ancestor component's concern.

It can also be helpful to think about state in the context of (re)rendering the component. Ask yourself if the component needs to change how it behaves/looks after it's mounted. If so, then condition that re-render on a state variable.

Comment: Although this is a good answer, the fact that a state is in fact describes a state inside of a component that may be a array, string, int or whatever. While a prob is just the short for property, that can be given to child components like parameters in other languages. It is still a state that is a property inside of a child component. so the diffrence to me is just the current belonging I guess

Answer (score 67):

The props vs state summary I like best is here: [react-guide](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md) Big hat tip to those guys. Below is an edited version of that page:

---

## props vs state

**tl;dr** If a Component needs to alter one of its attributes at some point in time, that attribute should be part of its state, otherwise it should just be a prop for that Component.

---

#### props

Props (short for properties) are a Component's configuration. They are received from above and immutable as far as the Component receiving them is concerned. A Component cannot change its props, but it is responsible for putting together the props of its child Components. Props do not have to just be data -- callback functions may be passed in as props.

#### state

The state is a data structure that starts with a default value when a Component mounts. It may be mutated across time, mostly as a result of user events.

A Component manages its own state internally. Besides setting an initial state, it has no business fiddling with the state of its children. You might conceptualize state as private to that component.

#### Changing props and state

```
                                                   props   state
    Can get initial value from parent Component?    Yes     Yes
    Can be changed by parent Component?             Yes     No
    Can set default values inside Component?*       Yes     Yes
    Can change inside Component?                    No      Yes
    Can set initial value for child Components?     Yes     Yes
    Can change in child Components?                 Yes     No
```

- Note that both props and state initial values received from parents override default values defined inside a Component.

### Should this Component have state?

State is optional. Since state increases complexity and reduces predictability, a Component without state is preferable. Even though you clearly can't do without state in an interactive app, you should avoid having too many Stateful Components.

#### Component types

**Stateless Component** Only props, no state. There's not much going on besides the render() function. Their logic revolves around the props they receive. This makes them very easy to follow, and to test.

**Stateful Component** Both props and state. These are used when your component must retain some state. This is a good place for client-server communication (XHR, web sockets, etc.), processing data and responding to user events. These sort of logistics should be encapsulated in a moderate number of Stateful Components, while all visualization and formatting logic should move downstream into many Stateless Components.

#### sources

- [Question about 'props' and 'state' - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/hAldztPzQgI)
- [Thinking in React: Identify where your state should live](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live)

Comment: what do you mean by "state initial value received from parent"? As far as I know the state is defined only in the scope of a single component and can not be changed from the outside directly.

Comment: @MaximKuzmin I believe that is a reference to the common pattern of taking in a prop like 'initialColor' to initialize a state like 'color'. The state is initially given the value from the prop (received from the parent) and then continues to act like regular state after that. It might be a little confusing to include that in an introduction to state vs. props, but it is an important pattern to know.

Answer (score 30):

The key difference between props and state is that state is internal and controlled by the component itself while props are external and controlled by whatever renders the component.

```jsx
function A(props) {
  return <h1>{props.message}</h1>
}

render(<A message=”hello” />,document.getElementById(“root”));
```

---

```jsx
class A extends React.Component{  
  constructor(props) {  
    super(props)  
    this.state={data:"Sample Data"}  
  }  
  render() {
    return(<h2>Class State data: {this.state.data}</h2>)  
  } 
}

render(<A />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[image: State VS Props]

- State can be changed (Mutable)
- Whereas Props can't (Immutable)

Answer (score 25):

> **props** (short for “properties”) and **state** are both plain JavaScript
>   objects. While both hold information that influences the output of
>   render, they are different in one important way: props get passed to
>   the component (similar to function parameters) whereas **state** is
>   managed within the component (similar to variables declared within a
>   function).

So simply **state** is limited to your current component but **props** can be pass to any component you wish... You can pass the **state** of the current component as **prop** to other components...

Also in React, we have **stateless components** which only have props and not internal state...

The example below showing how they work in your app:

**Parent** (state-full component):

```
class SuperClock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "Alireza", date: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Clock name={this.state.name} date={this.state.date} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child** (state-less component):

```
const Clock = ({name}, {date}) => (
    <div>
      <h1>{`Hi ${name}`}.</h1>
      <h2>{`It is ${date}`}.</h2>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 15):

Basically, the difference is that ***state*** is something like attributes in OOP : it's something **local** to a class (component), used to better describe it. ***[Props](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic)*** are like parameters - they are **passed** to a component from the caller of a component (the parent) : as if you called a function with certain parameters.

Answer (score 8):

Both **state** and **props** in react are used to control data into a component, generally props are set by parent and passed to child components and they are fixed throughout the component. For **data that is going to change,** we have to use state. And props are **immutable** while states are **mutable**, if you want to change props you can do from parent component and then pass it to child components.

Answer (score 7):

as I learned while working with react.

- **props** are used by a component **to get data from external environment** i.e another **component** ( pure, functional or class) or a **general class** or **javascript/typescript** code
- **states** are used **to manage the internal environment of a component** means the **data changes** inside the **component**

Answer (score 6):

Props : Props is nothing but property of component and react component is nothing but a javascript function.

```
  class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <h1>Hello {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
  }
```

const element = ;

here `<Welcome name="Sara" />` passing a object {name : 'Sara'} as props of Welcome component. To pass data from one parent component to child component we use props.
Props is immutable. During a component’s life cycle props should not change (consider them immutable).

State: state is accessible only within Component. To keep track of data within component we use state. we can change state by setState. If we need to pass state to child we have to pass it as props.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  updateCount() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (<button
              onClick={() => this.updateCount()}
            >
              Clicked {this.state.count} times
            </button>);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

State:

1. states are mutable.
2. states are associated with the individual components can't be used by other components.
3. states are initialize on component mount.
4. states are used for rendering dynamic changes within component.

props:

1. props are immutable.
2. you can pass props between components.
3. props are mostly used to communicate between components.You can pass from parent to child directly. For passing from child to parent
   you need use concept of lifting up states.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
  render()
  {
     return(
        <div>
            <Child name = {"ron"}/>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component{
{
    render(){
      return(
         <div>
              {this.props.name}
        </div>
      );
     }
}
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 9
}

Answer (score 4):

**state** - It is a special mutable property that hold a Component data. it has default value when Componet mounts.

**props** - It is a special property which is immutable by nature and used in case of pass by value from parent to child. props are just a communation channel between Components, always moving from top (parent) to buttom(child).

**below are complete example of combinding the state & props :-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>state&props example</title>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.8/dist/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.8/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

            var TodoList = React.createClass({
                render(){
                    return <div className='tacos-list'>
                                {
                                    this.props.list.map( ( todo, index ) => {
                                    return <p key={ `taco-${ index }` }>{ todo }</p>;
                            })}
                            </div>;
                }
            });

            var Todo = React.createClass({
                getInitialState(){
                    return {
                        list : [ 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Beans' ]       
                    }
                },
                handleReverse(){
                    this.setState({list : this.state.list.reverse()});
                },
                render(){
                    return <div className='parent-component'>
                              <h3 onClick={this.handleReverse}>List of todo:</h3>
                              <TodoList list={ this.state.list }  />
                           </div>;
                }
            });

            ReactDOM.render(
                <Todo/>,
                document.getElementById('root')
            );

        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Props:** represents "read-only" data, that are immutable and refer to attributes from parents component.

**State:** represents mutable data, that ultimately affects what is rendered on the page  and managed by internally by the component itself and change overtime commonly due to User input.

Answer (score 4):

**Props**

- props use to pass data in the child component
- props change a value outside a component(child component)

**State**

- state use inside a class component
- state change a value inside a component
- If you render the page, you call setState to update DOM(update page
  value)

State has an important role in react

Answer (score 3):

Basically, props and state are two ways the component can know what and how to render. Which part of the application state belongs to state and which to some top-level store, is more related to your app design, than to how React works. The simplest way to decide, IMO, is to think, whether this particular piece of data is useful for application as a whole, or it's some local information. Also, it's important to not duplicate state, so if some piece of data can be calculated from props - it should calculated from props.

For example, let's say you have some dropdown control (which wraps standart HTML select for custom styling), which can a) select some value from list, and b) be opened or closed (i.e., the options list displayed or hidden).
Now, let's say your app displays a list of items of some sort and your dropdown controls filter for list entries. Then, it would be best to pass active filter value as a prop, and keep opened/closed state local. Also, to make it functional, you would pass an onChange handler from parent component, which would be called inside dropdown element and send updated information (new selected filter) to the store immediately. On the other hand, opened/closed state can be kept inside dropdown component, because the rest of the application doesn't really care if the control is opened, until user actually changes it value.

The following code is not completely working, it needs css and handling dropdown click/blur/change events, but I wanted to keep example minimal. Hope it helps to understand the difference.

```
const _store = {
    items: [
    { id: 1, label: 'One' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Two' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Three', new: true },
    { id: 4, label: 'Four', new: true },
    { id: 5, label: 'Five', important: true },
    { id: 6, label: 'Six' },
    { id: 7, label: 'Seven', important: true },
    ],
  activeFilter: 'important',
  possibleFilters: [
    { key: 'all', label: 'All' },
    { key: 'new', label: 'New' },
    { key: 'important', label: 'Important' }
  ]
}

function getFilteredItems(items, filter) {
    switch (filter) {
    case 'all':
        return items;

    case 'new':
        return items.filter(function(item) { return Boolean(item.new); });

    case 'important':
        return items.filter(function(item) { return Boolean(item.important); });

    default:
        return items;
  }
}

const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
            <div>
            My list:

            <ItemList   items={this.props.listItems} />
          <div>
            <Dropdown 
              onFilterChange={function(e) {
                _store.activeFilter = e.currentTarget.value;
                console.log(_store); // in real life, some action would be dispatched here
              }}
              filterOptions={this.props.filterOptions}
              value={this.props.activeFilter}
              />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
});

const ItemList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map(function(item) {
          return <div key={item.id}>{item.id}: {item.label}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

const Dropdown = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        isOpen: false
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <select 
            className="hidden-select" 
          onChange={this.props.onFilterChange}
          value={this.props.value}>
            {this.props.filterOptions.map(function(option) {
            return <option value={option.key} key={option.key}>{option.label}</option>
          })}
        </select>

        <div className={'custom-select' + (this.state.isOpen ? ' open' : '')} onClick={this.onClick}>
            <div className="selected-value">{this.props.activeFilter}</div>
          {this.props.filterOptions.map(function(option) {
            return <div data-value={option.key} key={option.key}>{option.label}</div>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  onClick: function(e) {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App 
    listItems={getFilteredItems(_store.items, _store.activeFilter)} 
    filterOptions={_store.possibleFilters}
    activeFilter={_store.activeFilter}
    />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

State is the way react deals with the information held by your component.

Let's suppose you have a component which need to fetch some data from the server. You usually would want to inform the user if the request is processing, if it has failed, etc. This is a piece of information which is just relevant for that specific component. This is where state enters the game.

Usually the best way to define state is as follows:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { key1: value1, key2: value2 }    
  }
}
```

but in the latests implementations of react native you can just do:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { key1: value1, key2: value2 }    
}
```

These two examples execute in the exact same way, it's just a syntax improvement.

So, what is different from just using object attributes as we always have in OO programming? Usually, the information held in your state is not meant to be static, it will change over time and your View will need to update in order to reflect this changes. State offers this functionality in a simple way.

State IS MEANT TO BE INMUTABLE! and I cannot make enough stress on this. What does this means? It means that you should NEVER do something like this.

```
 state.key2 = newValue;
```

The proper way of doing it is:

```
this.setState({ key2: newValue });
```

Using this.setState your component runs through the update cycle and if any part of the state changes, your Component render method will be called again to reflect this changes.

Check the react docs for an even more expanded explanation:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 3):

Props simply are shorthand for properties. Props are how components talk to each other. If you’re at all familiar with React then you should know that props flow downwards from the parent component.

There is also the case that you can have default props so that props are set even if a parent component doesn’t pass props down.

This is why people refer to React as having uni-directional data flow. This takes a bit of getting your head around and I’ll probably blog on this later, but for now just remember: data flows from parent to child. Props are immutable (fancy word for it not changing)

So we’re happy. Components receive data from the parent. All sorted, right?

Well, not quite. What happens when a component receives data from someone other than the parent? What if the user inputs data directly to the component?

Well, this is why we have state.

STATE

Props shouldn’t change, so state steps up. Normally components don’t have state and so are referred to as stateless. A component using state is known as stateful. Feel free to drop that little tidbit at parties and watch people edge away from you.

So state is used so that a component can keep track of information in between any renders that it does. When you setState it updates the state object and then re-renders the component. This is super cool because that means React takes care of the hard work and is blazingly fast.

As a little example of state, here is a snippet from a search bar (worth checking out this course if you want to learn more about React)

```
Class SearchBar extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
this.state = { term: '' };
 }
render() {
  return (
   <div className="search-bar">
   <input 
   value={this.state.term}
   onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} />
   </div>
   );
 }
onInputChange(term) {
  this.setState({term});
  this.props.onSearchTermChange(term);
 }
}
```

SUMMARY

Props and State do similar things but are used in different ways. The majority of your components will probably be stateless.

Props are used to pass data from parent to child or by the component itself. They are immutable and thus will not be changed.

State is used for mutable data, or data that will change. This is particularly useful for user input. Think search bars for example. The user will type in data and this will update what they see.

Answer (score 3):

In short.

> props values can't be changed [immutable]
>
> state values can be changed, using setState method [mutable]

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the initial question about props being immutable, they are said to be immutable *as far as the child component is concerned* but are of course changeable in the parent that is passing these props down.
A change in these in the parent will trigger a re-render of the child component with the updated props.

Answer (score 2):

In general, state of one component(parent) is prop for the child component.

1. State resides within a component where as props are passed from parent to 
   child.
2. Props are generally immutable.

   ```
   class Parent extends React.Component {
       constructor() {
           super();
           this.state = {
               name : "John",
           }
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <Child name={this.state.name}>
           )
       }
   }

   class Child extends React.Component {
       constructor() {
           super();
       }

       render() {
           return(
               {this.props.name} 
           )
       }
   }
   ```

In the above code, we have a parent class(Parent) which has name as its state which is passed to the child component(Child class) as a prop and the child component renders it using {this.props.name}

Answer (score 2):

In React the states store the data as well as the props. Its difference with the latter is that the stored data can be modified by different changes. These are nothing more than objects written in flat JavaScript, so they can contain data or codes, represent the information you want to model. If you need more details it is recommended that you see these publications
 [Use of the State in React](https://blog.devsun.eu/react/2019/01/12/empleo-del-state-en-react/) and
 [Use of Props in React](https://blog.devsun.eu/react/2019/01/05/empleo-de-props-en-react/)

Answer (score 2):

The key difference between props and state is that state is internal and controlled by the component itself while props are external and controlled by whatever renders the component.

Comment: Indeed, though this answer is very "basic" it also show that props aren't limited to only be passed by parents, they can even be variables coming from another application such a backend in Java

Answer (score 1):

This is my current point of view regarding the explanation between state and props

1. State is like your local variable inside your component. You can manipulate
   the value of state by using set state. You can then pass the value of state
   to your child component for example.
2. Props is the value that exactly located inside your redux store, this actually 
   comes from state that's originated from reducer. Your component
   should be connected to redux to get the value from props. You can also pass
   your props value to your child component

Answer (score 1):

You have some data that is being entered by users somewhere in the application.

1. the component in which the data is being entered should have this data in its **state** because it needs to manipulate and change it during data entry
2. anywhere else in the application the data should be passed down as **props** to all the other components

So yes the props are changing but they are changed at the 'source' and will then simply flow down from there.  So props are immutable **in the context of the component receiving them**.

E.g. a reference data screen where users edit a list of suppliers would manage this in state, which would then have an action cause the updated data to be saved in ReferenceDataState which could be one level below AppState and then this supplier list would be passed as props to all the components that needed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Some differences between “state” and “props” in react.

React controls and renders DOM based on state. There are two types of component states: props is the state that transfers between components, and state is internal state of components. Props is used for data transfer from the parent component to the child component. The components also have their own state inside: state which can only be modified inside the component.

Generally the state of certain component could be the props of the child component ,props will be passed to children which is stated inside the rendering method of the parent component

Answer (score 1):

From:  Andrea Chiarelli book “Beginning React: Simplify your frontend development workflow and enhance the user experience of your applications with React” :

Every React component has a **props** property. The purpose of this property is to collect data input passed to the component itself. **JSX** attribute is attached to a React element, a property with the same name is attached to the **props** object. So, we can access the passed data by using the attached property. In addition, the immutability of **props** allows us to think of **components** as **pure functions**, which are functions that have no side effects (since they don't change their input data). We can think of data passing from one component to another as a unidirectional data flow, from the parent component toward the child components. This gives us a more controllable system.

React provides a mechanism to support the automatic rendering of a component when data changes. Such a mechanism is based on the concept of **state**. React **state** is a property that represents data that changes over time. Every component supports the **state** property, but it should be used carefully. Components that store data that can change over time are said to be **stateful components**. A **stateful component** stores the **state** in the **this.state** property. To inform a component that the state has changed, you must use the **setState()** method. **State** initialization is the only case where you can assign a value to the **this.state** property without using **setState()**.

**setState()** merges new data with old data already contained in the state, and overwrites the previous state
**setState()** triggers the execution of the **render()** method, so you should never call **render()** explicitly

Answer (score 1):

**State** is a special variable in react and is used to re-render component whenever it updates

**State** is private to the component itself. I.e, it cannot be accessed or modified outside of component. setState/hook used to update state. Whenever state update, component re renders

**State** is mutable

**Props** are inputs to component and render content using props data

**Props** are immutable(Object.Frozen= true)

Answer (score 1):

we can change states value but we can not change props value , or we can say props is immutable and states is mutable

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain **state** and **props** in a simple way to you:

### state

we use *states* to store some data. it's also like a variable that when you change it, your component will render again.

to use states you need to import `useState` hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
const [state_name,function_name] = useState(initial_value);
```

you can access your state by `state_name` and you can change it and set a new value to it by `function_name`.

**more info:** https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

### props

It is a mechanism to send data from one component to other. it also looks like properties in CSS. for example:

```
<Component props_value={custom_function} />
```

you can send a custom function to Component and receive it to be manipulate.

**more info:** https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

React Components use state to READ/WRITE the internal variables that can be changed/mutated by for example:

```
this.setState({name: 'Lila'})
```

React props is special object that allow programmer to get variables and methods from Parent Component into Child Component.

It's something like a Windows and doors of the house. Props are also immutable Child Component can not change/update them.

There are couple of the methods that help to listen when props are changed by Parent Component.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation is :
STATE is local state of component for example colour = "blue" or animation=true etc . Use this.setState to change state of component.
PROPS is how components talk to each other (send data from parent to child) and make components reusable .

Answer (score 0):

State is your data, is mutable, you can do anything you need with it, props is read only data, usually when you pass props you have already work with your data and you need the child component to render it or if your props is a function u call it to perform a task

Answer (score 0):

**The state is the origin of truth, where your data lives.**
You can say the state manifests itself via props.

Providing props to components is what keeps your UI in sync with your data.
A component is really just a function that returns markup.

Given **the same props** (data for it to display) it will always produce the **same markup**.

So the props are like the pipelines that carry the data from the origin to the functional components.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that state are private to a component  and can be changed inside that component only while props are just static value and key for child component which is passed through parent component and can't be changed inside the child component

Answer (score 0):

- **props**  --- you can not change its value.
- **states** --- you can change its value in your code, but it would be active when a render happens.

Answer (score 0):

React Components use state to READ/WRITE the internal variables that can be changed/mutated by for example:

```
this.setState({name: 'Lila'})
```

React props is special object that allow programmer to get variables and methods from Parent Component into Child Component.

It's something like a Windows and doors of the house. Props are also immutable Child Component can not change/update them.

There are couple of the methods that help to listen when props are changed by Parent Component.

Answer (score 0):

State resides within a component where as props are passed from parent to child.
Props are generally immutable.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name : "John",
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Child name={this.state.name}>
        )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return(
            {this.props.name} 
        )
    }
}
```

In the above code, we have a parent class(Parent) which has name as its state which is passed to the child component(Child class) as a prop and the child component renders it using {this.props.name}

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is states can be only be handled inside of components and props are handled outside of the components.If we are getting data from outside and handled ,in that case we should use states.

Answer (score 0):

Both props and states are the same in a way that both triggers the rerendering. the difference is that props come from parent components and states are managed in the current component. so states are mutable and props are immutable

Answer (score 0):

- props are the JavaScript object, passed into a Component, that holds the configuration properties.
- props are immutable by the receiving Component
- state is the JavaScript object, managed within the Component, that holds its internal state.
- Updates to either trigger a re-render

Comment: Makes sense. Can you provide a quote and link to where you got that info?

Answer (score 0):

Put simply:

- State is managed by a component on its own. It is reusable, private to the component and modifiable.
- Props are passed from parent to child. It is a unidirectional flow and readonly for child component. State of the parent component can be passed as props to a child component.

Answer (score 0):

**React props** are used to send information to the child component, Most of the time, your child components are stateless, which means they represent data/information which its parent gives to it,

On the other hand, **the state** deals with handling the component itself, the state can be changed within a component with the help of setState and useState hooks.

**For example**

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruit: 'apple'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(){
    this.setState({fruit: 'mango'})
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <Child  fruit={this.state.fruit} />
      <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Change state</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This parent class is changing its state from apple to mango when the button is clicked and passing its state as a prop to the child component. Now the child component without even having a state is showing different heading depending upon the state of the parent.

```
class Child extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <h1>I have received a prop {this.props.fruit}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

So on the root level, props are the parent communicating to its child while the state is to describe the parent situation etc.

Answer (score 0):

**state**: is internally valuable which means only valid in that class component, so you can not pass it to another component.

**props**: On the other hand, you can pass props from parent to child or from child to parent.

Answer (score 0):

To give the simplest explanation, complementary to the above comments:

According to React's [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#storing-a-history-of-moves), they treat "state" as

```
To “remember” things, components use state.
```

and props can be understood as a variable passing around from parent component to child.

If you want to remember something in your app, you would use state and if you want to pass around data, you will use props.

Let me give you another analogy, let's say you are trying to add the sequence of the first 25 Natural numbers in your head.

```
1+2+3+4.....
```

You will start with 1, and then you add 2 into it, you will at 3 now and then you will add to your current total(6 now), and then you will add 4 to your current total (6) and so new current total is 10.

The current total is the `state` of your program and let's say you need to find the average of your total sum. You will take that sum and put it into an equation, you will pass around your sum as `props`.

Hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between React `props` and `state` is that `props` are immutable, once a component received a `props` it can not change its value, while in on the other hand React `state` are mutable and Component is free to change its value as many time is required.

Answer (score 0):

**"Props"** are external inputs passed a component ([1](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html,)), **"state"** is internal, private data managed by the component ([2](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html,)).

Answer (score 0):

In react we usually use modules to separate components. Sometimes separated components need to share data within them. If a parent component has some data which should be shared on the child components than props is the solution. We can share the data using props from the parents to children. Props is immutable, meaning you cannot change the data.

On the other hand state is used to keep track of any changes in data. You can consider the state as a storage of data and a function that can update that data. State is mutable. You can change state using setState function within the same component

Answer (score 0):

There are a few key differences between props and state in React. Props are immutable - once they are set, they cannot be changed. State, on the other hand, can be changed at any time. Props are also passed down from parent to child, while state is local to a single component.

Answer (score 0):

**State** represents the internal mutable data of a component and is managed within the component itself. It can be updated using setState() and triggers re-renders.

**Props** are read-only data passed from parent to child components, used for customization. They flow in one direction and cannot be modified by the child component. State is local, while props facilitate data and behavior sharing between components

Answer (score -2):

Props are values, objects or arrays passed into a component on render.  These props are often values needed within the component to create the UI, set certain default functionality or used to populate fields.  Props can also come in the form of functions passed down from the parent component that can be invoked by the child.

State is managed within the component (child or parent).

Here is a definition I found to support this:

[image]