# Using Props And State To Pass Value Of Select Box To Child Component React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I am going to be filtering a table based on the values in a selection box. I am having trouble understanding `state` and `props` within `react.js`. Once I pass the value in I can easily do the filtering but I am trying to do this the "react" way.

**Question**

How do I pass the value of `SelectionBox` when it is selected or changed to `TableDisplay` when the user selects one of the options?

**Example**

```
class SelectionBox extends React.Component {
                render() {
                return <div className="filter">
              <label for="business">Filter by Status
                                <select id="business" name="business">
                                    <option value="all">All Requests</option>
                                    <option value="approved">Approved</option>
                                    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                                    <option value="denied">Denied</option>
                                </select>
                </label>
            </div>;
        }
}

class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <div className="wrapper">
            <h1>Requests</h1>
            <SelectionBox /> 
            <div><table className="table">
                    <tr className="seperate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td><td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
                  {Object.keys(requests).map(function(key) {  
    let styling = "bg-plain";

    if (requests[key].status == "Approved") {
        styling = "bg-success";
    } else if (requests[key].status == "Denied") {
        styling = "bg-danger";
    }

    return <tr className={styling}>
        <td>{requests[key].title}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].status}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].created_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].updated_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>;

    })}
                    </table>
          </div></div>;
      }
}
```

**Research**

From reading I think what I need to implement here is, 
Inside `SelectionBox`

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
// Something referring to the state of the select box here
    };
  };
```

Then access `props` from within `TableDisplay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to clear up your understanding of `state` vs `props` you should reference this answer: [What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

Second, to pass the value of the `SelectionBox` to the `TableDisplay` you need to create some kind of parent `TableDisplayContainer` component that contains both components. The `TableDisplayContainer` will store the value of the `select` dropdown in its state. To do this, you need to pass a function as a prop to the `SelectionBox` that will handle the `onChange` event of the `select` dropdown (you can call it `handleOnChange` for example). The `handleOnChange` method will set the value to the state of the `TableDisplayContainer`. Once it's set in state, you can pass the value to the `TableDisplay` component as a prop.

Here's a quick example of what you can do:

```
class SelectionBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="filter">
        <label for="business">Filter by Status
          <select
            id="business"
            name="business"
            onChange={this.props.handleOnChange}
          >
              <option value="all">All Requests</option>
              <option value="approved">Approved</option>
              <option value="pending">Pending</option>
              <option value="denied">Denied</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Do your filtering with this value
    const {selectValue} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Requests</h1>
        <SelectionBox /> 
        <div><table className="table">
              <tr className="seperate"><td>Title</td><td>Status</td><td>Created</td><td>Updated</td><td>Delete</td></tr>
            {Object.keys(requests).map(function(key) {  
        let styling = "bg-plain";

        if (requests[key].status == "Approved") {
        styling = "bg-success";
        } else if (requests[key].status == "Denied") {
        styling = "bg-danger";
        }

        return <tr className={styling}>
        <td>{requests[key].title}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].status}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].created_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td>{requests[key].updated_at.slice(0, 10)}</td>
        <td><a href="">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>;

        })}
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class TableDisplayContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectValue: 'all' // use this as default
    }
  }

  handleOnChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      selectValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {selectValue} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <SelectionBox
          handleOnChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <TableDisplay
          selectValue={selectValue}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On React state is something that is relevant to the component itself, and props are passed down to it (or have a default value in case of omission). The [handle events guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) explains my solution below:

You can pass a onChange handler to selectionBox and use it on your TableDisplay component

```
  class SelectionBox extends React.Component {
    render () {
      //...
        <select onChange={this.props.onChange}>
          //...
        </select>
      //...
    }
  }
  SelectionBox.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }
  class TableDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.onSelection = this._onSelection.bind(this)
      this.state = {
        selectValue: null
      }
    }
    _onSelection (ev) {
      this.setState({selectValue:ev.target.value})
    }
    render () {
      //...
      <SelectionBox onChange={this.props.onSelection} />
      //...
      <h1>{'The select value is '+ this.state.selectValue}</h1>
    }
}
```

Notice that I used [propTypes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) just to make sure that I don't forget.

Comment: In your example is         SelectionBox.propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  } supposed to be outside of the class?

Comment: Yes it would be a static property. If you use the right thing on babel you can use the static keyword but that is not the default