# Passing value from select box as argument in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a React app that needs to update the state and call an API based on the option a user selects from the Select Box. As I am unable to place the function call in the `<option></option>` tags I need to retrieve the `value` from the option tags when `onChange` is called.

I have created a `selectValue` value in the app state to update and have tried to emulate the solution in the below post.

[Using Props And State To Pass Value Of Select Box To Child Component React.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662073/using-props-and-state-to-pass-value-of-select-box-to-child-component-react-js.)
The issue I am having, however, is that I do not know how to select and pass the `value` from the selected option.

I have tested it by hardcoding a value to be passed by `onHandleSelectValue` in the `ListBooks.js` file. When I do this the state updates as expected.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListBooks from './ListBooks'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends Component {
  state = {
    books: [],
    selectValue: 'wantToRead'
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll()
    .then((books) => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        books
      }))
    })
  }

  updateShelf = (book) => {
    const shelf = this.state.selectValue
    this.state.books.forEach(b => {
      if(b.id === book.id) {
        console.log('Shelf: ' + this.state.selectValue)
        b.shelf = shelf
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
          books: currentState.books
        }))
      }
    });
    BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
  }

  handleSelectValue(option) {
    console.log('handleSelectValue: ' + option)
    this.setState((currentState) => ({
      selectValue: option
    }))
    console.log('handleSelectValue + selectValue: ' + option)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
          <ListBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          onHandleSelectValue={this.handleSelectValue.bind(this)}
          />
        )} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default BooksApp
```

ListBooks.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './App.css'

const shelves = [
  {
    key: 'currentlyReading',
    name: 'Currently Reading'
  },
  {
    key: 'wantToRead',
    name: 'Want To Read'
  },
  {
    key: 'read',
    name: 'Read'
  },
  // {
  //   key: '',
  //   name: 'None'
  // }
];

class ListBooks extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       books: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    state = {
        showSearchPage: false,
        query: ''
      }

    render() {

        const { books, onUpdateShelf, onHandleSelectValue } = this.props

        function getBooksForShelf(shelfKey) {
          return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelfKey);
        }

        console.log(books);

        return(
            <div className="app">
            {this.state.showSearchPage ? (
              <div className="search-books">
                <div className="search-books-bar">
                  <a className="close-search" onClick={() => this.setState({ showSearchPage: false })}>Close</a>
                  <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
                    {/*
                      NOTES: The search from BooksAPI is limited to a particular set of search terms.
                      You can find these search terms here:
                      https://github.com/udacity/reactnd-project-myreads-starter/blob/master/SEARCH_TERMS.md
                      However, remember that the BooksAPI.search method DOES search by title or author. So, don't worry if
                      you don't find a specific author or title. Every search is limited by search terms.
                    */}
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title or author"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="search-books-results">
                  <ol className="books-grid"></ol>
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="list-books">
                <div className="list-books-title">
                  <h1>My Reads</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="list-books-content">
                  <div>
                    { shelves.map((shelf) => (
                      <div key={shelf.key} className="bookshelf">
                        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelf.name}</h2>
                          <div className="bookshelf-books">
                            <ol className="books-grid">
                        <li>
                          { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).map((book) => (
                            <div key={book.id} className="book">
                              <div className="book-top">
                               <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})` }}></div>
                                <div className="book-shelf-changer"> 
                                 <select onChange={() => onUpdateShelf(book, onHandleSelectValue('read'))}>
                                  <option value="none" disabled >Move to...</option>
                                    <option value="currentlyReading" >Currently Reading</option>
                                    <option value="wantToRead" >Want to Read</option>
                                    <option value="read" >Read</option>
                                    <option value="none" >None</option>
                                   </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                             <div className="book-authors">{book.author}</div>
                            </div>
                            ))}
                          </li>
                        </ol>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                    )) }
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="open-search">
                  <a onClick={() => this.setState({ showSearchPage: true })}>Add a book</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListBooks
```

Comment: can you check the like  `<select onChange={(e) => onUpdateShelf(book, onHandleSelectValue(e.target.value))` , it might help.

Answer (score 2):

So using suggestion provided by @Praveen Kumar.

I removed the extra handlers and just changed the below line to pass the `value` from selected option as an argument.

```
<select onChange={(e) => onUpdateShelf(book, e.target.value)}>
```