# Want to know more about Props & State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I tried reading books and watching videos about JS and React, but still I don't have better understanding of React-Props & States. 
Can some one please explain me in details.

Comment: Please check react documentation.

Comment: This is covered in the React docs. Is there a specific confusion?

Comment: Documents will surely help :). and this too https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Props**
Components Props can be thought of as a component's options. They're given as arguments to a component and look exactly like HTML attributes.

It's worth noting that a component should never change its props, they're immutable. If a component has data that's mutable, use the state object.

```
var Photo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className='photo'>
        <img src={this.props.src} />
        <span>{this.props.caption}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Photo src='http://example.com/lkevsb9' caption='Hong Kong!' />, document.body);
```

**State**
The state object is internal to a component. It holds data which can change over time.

Before we can use state, we need to declare a default set of values for the initial state. This is done by defining a method called getInitialState() and returning an object.

State is set using the setState method. Calling setState triggers UI updates.
Setting state should only be done from inside the component.

```
var InterfaceComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState : function() {
    return {
      name : "chris"
    };
  },
  handleClick : function() {
    this.setState({
      name : "bob"
    });
  },
  render : function() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
      hello {this.state.name}
    </div>;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  <InterfaceComponent />,
  document.body
);
```