# React: Uncaught TypeError between parent and child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've split a component into a parent and child element. I'm passing data from the parent to the child via states but receiving an *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageSource' of null* which is odd because I'm following the same process as another element of the application. I've also followed the Components and Props documentation but am still a little stumped.

If I've defined the state, set it, and added it as a property to the child, how come the state is still *null*?

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
     imageSource: [],
     imageTitles: [],
   }
 }

 componentDidMount(){

 ...
 ...
 // grabbing stuff from Dropbox API
 ...
 ...

  .then(function(){
    that.setState({

      imageSource: sources,
      imageTitles: titles,

    });
   });



 render(){
   return(
      <Child imageSource={this.state.imageSource} imageTitles=
      {this.state.imageTitles} />
   );
 }
}



class Child extends React.Component{

 render(){
    if(!this.state.imageSource.length)
      return null;

      let titles = this.state.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)

      let images = this.state.imageSource.map((el, i) =>

        <div className="imageContainer">
           <img key={i} className='images' src={el}/>
           <div className="imageTitle">{titles[i]}</div>
        </div>
       )

    return (
      <div className="ChildWrapper">
         {images}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the child you will receive the variables as props (not state).

In your case this code should work

```
if(!this.props.imageSource.length)
  return null;

  let titles = this.props.imageTitles.map((el, i) => <p>{el}</p>)

  let images = this.props.imageSource.map((el, i) =>

    <div className="imageContainer">
       <img key={i} className='images' src={el}/>
       <div className="imageTitle">{titles[i]}</div>
    </div>
   )
```

Take a look to this question, I think it will help you to understand the differences.

[What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things stand out. This piece of code here:

```
class Child extends React.Component{

 render(){
    if(!this.state.imageSource.length)
      return null;
```

Is wrong because your Child component has **no state**. You're not declaring any state in your `Child` component, and you probably shouldn't. What it does have is **props** passed down from the `Parent` component. This is a critical part of learning react. What you would want to check here is `if(!this.props.imageSource.length)` and edit your additional code that calls `this.state` and replace with `this.props`.

Another thing I noticed is this:

```
 that.setState({

      imageSource: sources,
      imageTitles: titles,

    });
```

Why `that.setState({...})` ? That's confusing, and there really is no reason you should ever call it. It should always be `this.setState({...})` If you're doing some re-binding of `this`, you're doing something wrong as that should not ever be the case and can lead to bugs pretty easily.