# Why use props in react if you could always use state data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that there's two ways to pass components data: props and state. But why would one need a prop over a state? It seems like the state object could just be used inside the component, so why pass the prop parameters in markup?

Comment: `prop` is the object passed by the parent component to child component and `state` is local to a particular component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

Comment: "I understand that there's two ways to pass components data: props and state" No, there's only one way to pass data: props. state holds data. it's the state of the component. to pass this state data to another component you need props

Comment: you don't actually pass state, you pass a property from a state via a prop of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

Props are set externally by a parent component.  E.g.;

```
render() {
    return <ChildComponent someProp={someValue}/>;
}
```

State is set internally, and often triggered by an user event within a child.  E.g.;

```
handleUserClickedButton: () {
    this.setState({
        buttonClicked: true
    });
},

render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleUserClickedButton}/>;
}
```

So, props are a way for data to go from parent to child.  State is a way for data to be managed within a singular component, and possibly have changes to that data triggered by children.  In effect, they represent data traveling in 2 opposite directions, and the way in which they are passed is entirely unique.

Comment: so you can't pass state between a parent to child? for example, can't the parent change the state and then the child gets the new state.

Comment: If the child "gets the new state", it does so in the form of receiving a prop;  `<ChildComponent someProp={this.state.someState}/>` is a valid and typical piece of code that would take a value from state and pass it down to a child as a prop.

Comment: why does the child not just have a shared state? for example, each component (or sub-component) could just do a "this.state" to get the current state of the program

Comment: Because each component has a unique state.  State is not shared at all.

Comment: the same way you can't access variables from other functions. _scope_, _context_ are the basics of javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways  to "pass" or access data from outside your component but `state` is not one of them.
The two ways are:
[Props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) - which a parent component pass down to the child component.
[Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) - which you can "skip" the direct parent in the tree.

The `state` is an internal object which no other component has access to it unless you pass it explicitly (via the two ways mentioned above).

So basically your question is not accurate as you can't really compare the two.
I think what you are really asking  is why using a state-less instead of a state-full component.
Which you can find an answer here in Stack-overflow or in other websites.

**Edit**
A followup to some of your comments.

> why does the child not just have a shared state? for example, each
>   component (or sub-component) could just do a "this.state" to get the
>   current state of the program

1. The same way you can't share or access private objects in other
   functions.
2. This is by design, you share things explicitly and you will pass
   only what the component needs. For example, look it this page of
   stack-overflow, lets say the voting buttons are components, why
   would i pass them the whole state if it only needs the vote count
   and 2 `onClick` event listeners? Should i pass the current logged in
   user or maybe the entire answers rendered in this page?

> so you can't pass state between a parent to child? for example, can't
>   the parent change the state and then the child gets the new state

This is exactly what the `props` or `context` should do, provide an API for sharing data between parents and children though we keep it in a one way data flow, from parents to children, you can't pass props upwards. but you invoke handlers passed down to your child components and pass data through that handler.