# ReactJS passing state to another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, react-props

i have problem in accesing the state on the other component. I am beginner in using the reactjs. I am still confuse on how to use the state and props. I am getting the input which will be set to the state as username then I will pass it to the formDetails component and use it when the handleSubmit triggers. can someone help me I would appreciate any comments, answers, suggestions.

```
//Components
 class DaysForm extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        username: ""
    };
    this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
}

onCalculate(e) {
    $("#myModal").modal();
}

updateInput(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>How many days are in a full time working week?</p>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={this.updateInput}
            />
            <p>How many days a week will this employee work?</p>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" />
            <br />
            <center>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-default"
                    onClick={this.onCalculate.bind(this)}
                >
                    Calculate
                </button>
            </center>
        </div>
    );
}
}

class FormDetails extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    //console.log here the state that is comming from the component
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Email Address:</p>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" />
            <p>Business Name:</p>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" />
            <p>Phone Number:</p>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" />
            <br />
            <center>
                <button
                    className="btn btn-default"
                    onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </button>
            </center>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: From what I can see here, the two components have no relationship to each other. Was your intention to render `FormDetails` in the `DaysForm` at some point or are they completely separated?

Comment: @theJuls they are completely separated. I just want to pass the state username to FormDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to set the `username` in the `DaysForm` component, and then upon `handleSubmit` being clicked, it will show up in the `FormDetails` component. Is that correct?

Assuming so, there are a couple things missing.

First of all, you are not currently rendering `FormDetails`  in the `DaysForm`. So right now, they have no relation to each other. Or at least not in the code you displayed. Are you using the `username` as a redux state perhaps which is share in the two components? Because this changes everything if that's the case.

The easier way to do this would be to have `FormDetails` be a child of `DaysForm` and then pass the `username` state as a prop in the `FormDetails` component. This will make it look something like this:

```
class DaysForm extends React.Component {
// your code

render(){
return(
      <div>
        <p>      
            How many days are in a full time working week?
        </p>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.updateInput}/>
        <p>      
            How many days a week will this employee work?
        </p>
        <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
        <br></br>
        <center>
            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.onCalculate.bind(this)}>Calculate</button>
        </center>

        <FormDetails username={this.state.username}/>
      </div>

  )
 }
}
```

However, you mentioned that the components have no relation to each other, I am assuming that there are no other components that can connect the two, so this complicates a bit when you want to pass in a state from one component to another. Based on the post's tags, I am assuming you are using Redux. If not, for this case I would encourage you to do so, since it will handle your state in between components. Of course if you haven't touched any of that yet, I will admit it is a whole new can of worms to open.

As for the difference between state and props. State usually belong to a component, you change them causing the component to rerender and they may be later passed in as a props for a child component (as shown in the example code). Props on the other hand come from other components and are immutable. [See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react). The way you are using the state in `DaysForm` seems to be just fine and is as expected, the main challenge here is figuring out how to pass that state to `FormDetails` when there are no obvious other components in between them.