# why props is used instead of state in state component in below provided link?

Tags: reactjs

I want code, to track live location using react.js so I have gone through this below provide link and I just want to know why props is used instead of state in state full component ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geolocated

Can someone help me why they used props?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

Comment: please fix your question

Comment: Rauniyar !! props can be used in stateless components and state is used in state full components ..but here my query is why are they used props in state full components?

Answer (score 1):

You're on wrong track. Props can be used either in stateful component or stateless component.

By meaning **state**ful component is not just for maintaining `states`. Nor **state**less component just for maintaining `props`.

```
stateful !== states
stateless !== props
```

You can take this for short:

```
stateful <=> states <=> props
stateless <=> props <=> states
```

Where you can see (in short, there's more... look at the references), stateful component passes the states/props, the child component can use props, stateless component links props and hooks the states. - You might feel difficulty reading this line of statement.

Come back later after following the references to understand what I wanted to say, you'll obviously know what I meant for.

If you want to look about the differences between props vs state, then look at attached duplicate post:

[What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

I would also suggest you to look at the docs about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Here's the link to the docs for props and states:

[Components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

[State and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

By reading these references, you should have clear understanding of props and states.