# How to make react component fetch data when props is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make my component re-render and fetch new data when the props is changed but I can't make it work.

```
export default class InfoTagEditor extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        $.get('/webapi/getData?componentId=' + this.props.id, function (data) {
            this.setState({value: data});
            this.initComponentsDropdownlist();
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

But this doesn't update the state at all...

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Kendo Editor in Render function:

```
Render(){
    return   <Editor
    name={"Editor"}
    value={this.state.value}
    change={this.onChangeEditor}
    resizable={true}
    />
}
```

What worked for me was:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps)
{
    if (this.props.Id !== nextProps.Id) {
        $.get('/webapi/GetData?Id=' + nextProps.Id, function (data) {
            this.setState({value: data});
            $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(this.state.value)
            return true;
        }.bind(this));
    }

    if (this.props.name !== nextProps.name) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But would this be the correct way of doing this? The Id and Name is corresponding, which means that everytime there is a new ID, there will also be a new Name.

Should I do this separate

```
this.setState({ value: data });
$('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(this.state.value)
```

or

```
 this.setState({ value: data },  
 $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(this.state.value));
```

Managed to get this work:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.id!== prevProps.id) {
        $.get('/webapi/GetData?id=' + this.props.id, function (data) {
            this.setState({ editorValue: data }, $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data)); 
        }.bind(this));
     }
}
```

Is this a correct way of doing the callback? and does it looks fine? :) or should I move the $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data) outside the setState?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

Comment: I think you should store your props in state and then instead of using props directly use state

Comment: is the request fired? do you get a response? do you get any exception?

Comment: call `this.initComponentsDropdownlist()` in `setState` callback, otherwise it can work on old data

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

First you should add a condition in order to prevent infinite loop (`setState -> componentDidUpdate -> setState -> componentDidUpdate ....`) : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop

Here is a possible solution

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
        $.get('/webapi/getData?componentId=' + this.props.id, (data) => {
           this.setState({ value: data });
           this.initComponentsDropdownlist();
        });
     }
}
```

Note that if the method `initComponentsDropdownlist` uses `this.state.value`, it should be called when `setState` is completed, so you should replace :

```
this.setState({ value: data });
this.initComponentsDropdownlist();
```

by

```
 this.setState({ value: data }, this.initComponentsDropdownlist);
```

Comment: I tried this, it seem like it should work? But the state with the data isn't updated it seems in my editor. Since it use the value state.

Comment: can you show us the code in the method `initComponentsDropdownlist` ? Does it use variable `this.state.value` ?

Comment: I updated the post with the component that uses this. Sorry but the  initComponentsDropdownlist  is wrong, it should be the editor that uses the value.

Comment: It seems like this package with the editor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-editor-react-wrapper has problem with updating...

I tried to remove the editor and the state changed perfectly.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't really know the `kendo` library, do you have a link to the documentation of this component ?

Comment: Hello @Olivier Boissé, should it be this.setState({ value: data }, this.initComponentsDropdownlist); or this.setState({ value: data }, this.initComponentsDropdownlist());

Comment: the second argument is a callback so it should be `this.setState({ value: data }, this.initComponentsDropdownlist);` or `this.setState({ value: data }, () => this.initComponentsDropdownlist());`

Comment: What does a callback mean my friend? :)  @Olivier Boissé

Here is the documentation for the library: 

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/overview

Comment: I tried to do this after the         $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(this.state.editorValue);
But I'm getting GetSelection error.

I also tried to call InitEditor, but it seem to just created another editor each time the componentdidupdate, instead of just updating the value.

Comment: Are you using Kendo React controls (if not, perhaps you should?)? According to https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/editor/api/EditorProps/ there is no `value` or `change` prop. Are you sure you're working with the correct version etc? Have you checked the sample? https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/editor/content/

Comment: I'm using this one @NSevens docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/editor/overview

Comment: you're running a react application, why not use React components from the same library? they are much more integrated in the react lifecycle

Comment: When I put it outside the Jquery Get, it seem to work fine. But the editor value only appear on the next re-render when I update the prop....

Comment: a callback is simply ia function that is passed as an argument of another function. it's often used when you want want to execute code asynchronously (after the end of an operation like an ajax call)

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I have updated the post. Could you check and tell me if there is any way I could do this different? Or if this is a bad way of doing it?

Comment: you don't need `return true` or `return false` in `componentDidUpdate`, so remove them. `setState` is **asynchronous** so `$('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(this.state.value)` is wrong, you should replace it by `$('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data)`

Comment: As you are using `jQuery` to update the value of your editor, the state `value` seems to become useless, maybe you don't need a state anymore

Comment: Should I include componentDidUpdate? Since I'm not sure what to put in there.
But in your opinion, should it work in componentDidUpdate? Because it seems like when the jquery set value, I need to re-render my component in order to "see the new" changes.

Comment: `this.setState({ editorValue: data }); $('#editor').data('kendoEditor').value(data));`

Answer (score -1):

use componentWillReceiveProps

```
export default class InfoTagEditor extends React.PureComponent {        
   componentWillReceiveProps(props)
   {
           $.get('/webapi/getData?componentId=' + props.id, function (data) 
           {
                this.setState({ value: data });
                this.initComponentsDropdownlist();
            }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Comment: it deprecated in react 16+

Comment: What should I use then? It doesn't seem that the state is set when I use shouldComponentUpdate.

componentWillReceiveProps()

Comment: if using react 15 then use componentWillReceiveProps