# React, Should I set state from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I always use props directly without set it to state and it works just fine, but should I really set state from props and then use that state instead. what's the difference?

```
Class A extends Component {
    ...some method,
    render() {
      return <>{this.props.message}</>
    }
}

Class A extends Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
          message: ''
       }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
       this.setState({message: this.props.message})
    }
    render() {
      return <>{this.state.message}</>
    }
}
```

Comment: only use state if you need to update data live in the UI. something like an input controller for instance. there are other use cases for state besides this (update a class name, loading flags... etc), but in general its when you need to have a component do something other than just render data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between state and props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need if the values are identical. Consider that every time you use `this.setState()` you cause an additional re-render of your component. A small price to pay, but something that can mean much more later on if you have let's say 10000 messages. So it wouldn't provide any benefit by updating `state`. Just use props directly.

It would make some sense to update state if you plan on using the props as an intermediary check. Let's say you have something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
   state = {
     display: none
   }

   componentDidUpdate(){
      if(this.props.data.length > 0){
        this.setState({
           display: true
        })
      }
   }

   render(){
     <div>
       { this.state.display ? "Show value" : "" }
     </div>
   }
}
```

We can use props to update a state-value that determines if we should display some content.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use data from props no need to update it to state it just add some 2 3 lines of code and additional execution of setState function but user will not feel any difference at all.