# React pass props from parent wrapper to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I need to pass props from wrapper to child component

Have a structure like this:

**CabinetBlockContainer.jsx**

**smallChild.jsx**

Right now my **smallChild.jsx** looks like:

```
return (
    <CabinetBlockContainer>
      <div className={props.className}>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="primary">
          {props.title}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="caption">{props.subtitle}</Typography>
      </div>
      <BalanceSmallBlock balance="1254.51" needIcon={props.needIcon} />
    </CabinetBlockContainer>
  );
```

and my  container looks like:

```
 return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <div className="block-wrapper" >

      </div>
    </div>
  );
})
```

I have many styles for my blocks, that's why I created wrapper(**CabinetBlockContainer**). I need to pass props from my CabinetBlockContainer to its child component. I don't really know is it the best practice, but seems normal.

I have tried to find in documentation how to pass props like this, but have any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{props.children}` inside your wrapper, it seems you want to do something like [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment).

Comment: Thanks, that wss the thing I was looking for. 
Thank you!

Found other solution export const CabinetBlockContainer = styled.div``
Which variant is better  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass props to a children while cloning it with new props

for better understanding how props and state work please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

and here is an example of previously answered same question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371612/7912447)