# ReactJS Change Sibling State via Parent

Tags: reactjs

My React structure is

```
- App
   |--SelectStudy
   |--ParticipantsTable
```

In `SelectStudy` there is a button whose click triggers a message to its sibling, `ParticipantsTable`, **via the `App` parent**. The first Child->Parent transfer works. But how do I implement the second Parent->Child transfer? See questions in comments.

**App**

```
class App extends Component { 

  myCallback(dataFromChild) {
      // This callback receives changes from SelectStudy Child Component's button click
      // THIS WORKS
      alert('SelectStudy Component sent value to Parent (App): ' + dataFromChild.label + " -> " + dataFromChild.value);
      // QUESTION: How to Update State of ParticipantsTable (SelectStudy's Sibling) next?
      // ........................................................
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className="App">
             <SelectStudy callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}></SelectStudy>
             <ParticipantsTable></ParticipantsTable>
          </div>
      );
}
```

**SelectStudy**

```
class SelectStudy extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: [],
            selectedStudy: null, 
            isButtonLoading: false
        };
        this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items, itemsForReactSelect, selectedStudy, isButtonLoading } = this.state;
        return <Button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Search</Button>;
    }

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.selectedStudy);
    }

}
```

**ParticipantsTable** - this needs to receive a certain variable, e.g. `study` in its State

```
class ParticipantsTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        //alert('Constructor');
        super(props);
        // Initial Definition of this component's state
        this.state = {
            study: null,
            items: [], 
            error: null
        };
    }

    // THIS METHOD IS AVAILABLE, BUT HOW TO CALL IT FROM App's myCallback(dataFromChild)?
    setStudy = (selectedStudy) => {
        this.setState({study: selectedStudy});
    }    

    render() {
        return ( <div>{this.state.study}</div> );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a classic anti-pattern, why not store the state for both things in App and pass props downwards. Simple solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state should live definitively at the `App` level, not in the child. State needs to live one level above the lowest common denominator that needs access to it. So if both `SelectStudy` and `ParticipantsTable` need access to the same bit of state data, then it *must* live in their closest common ancestor (or above).

This is a core concept of React, known as "lifting state up", so much so that it has its own page in the [official React documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

In your case, it would look something like this. Notice how state lives in only one place, at the `<App />` level, and is passed to children via props.

```js
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  // State lives here at the closest common ancestor of children that need it
  state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    items: [],
    selectedStudy: null,
    isButtonLoading: false
  };

  myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    this.setState(dataFromChild);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/* State is passed into child components here, as props */}
        <SelectStudy data={this.state} callbackFromParent={this.myCallback}></SelectStudy>
        <ParticipantsTable study={this.state.selectedStudy} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class SelectStudy extends React.Component {
  handleButtonClick = () => {
    // Here we execute a callback, provided by <App />, to update state one level up
    this.props.callbackFromParent({ ...this.props.selectedStudy, isButtonLoading: true });
  };

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items, itemsForReactSelect, selectedStudy, isButtonLoading } = this.props.data;

    return <Button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Search</Button>;
  }
}

// This component doesn't need to track any internal state - it only renders what is given via props
class ParticipantsTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.study}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: The one thing to be aware of to this method is that each state update to parent will re-render all children. Sometimes (and in this case) it might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to understand is the difference between `state` and `props`.

`state` is internal to a component while `props` are passed down from parents to children

Here is a [in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991366/what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props-in-react)

So you want to set a `state` in the parent that you can pass as `props` to children

1 set state in the parent

```
 this.state = {
  value: null
 }

 myCallback(dataFromChild) {
    this.setState({value: dataFromChild.value})

  }
```

2 pass it as a prop to the children

```
class ParticipantsTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            study: props.study,
            items: [], 
            error: null
        };
    }
```

Also, although not related to your question, if you learning `React` I suggest moving away from class-based components in favour of hooks and functional components as they have become more widely used and popular recently.